# Bluetooth Battery Level on Android Marshmallow

Tags: battery, bluetooth, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm using [LUXA2-Lavi O In-ear Wireless Earphone](http://luxa2.com/Audio_Solution/152/Lavi_O_In_ear_Wireless_Earphone/product.htm) on my [Nexus 6P](http://www.gethuawei.com/nexus6p) with latest [Android – Marshmallow](https://www.android.com/versions/marshmallow-6-0/) and I cannot find where I can see battery level for my Bluetooth device, I am however able to see battery level when using same headphones with iPhone, (seems like pretty essential feature to be missing), unless I just didn't find it...

Can someone tell me where I can find that? I do *NOT* want to install any 3rd party apps for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [Bluetooth documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#find) at Android Developers, it appears that this capability is based on **connected device** profile. Android supports this functionality from API level 18 (4.3). [How to get Bluetooth Headset battery status in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602224/how-to-get-bluetooth-headset-battery-status-in-android) from Stack Overflow indicate similarly, with vendor specific implementation links

> Generic Attribute Profile (GATT)—The GATT profile is a general specification for sending and receiving short pieces of data known as "attributes" over a BLE link. All current Low Energy application profiles are based on GATT.
>   The Bluetooth SIG defines many profiles for Low Energy devices. A profile is a specification for how a device works in a particular application. Note that a device can implement more than one profile. For example, a device could contain a heart rate monitor and a **battery level detector**

Perhaps, ios ecosystem enforces this  as  mandatory and hence you can see it on your ios device

Since you do not wish to use a third party app like [Potential Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paranoidgems.potential), it would be better to contact earphone OEM to ascertain

**Edit**  I don't have marshmallow so am not sure if this setting tweak will help [display-battery-percentage-android-marshmallow](http://www.androidauthority.com/display-battery-percentage-android-marshmallow-647273/)

Comment: +1 for `System UI Tuner`, however `Show embedded battery percentage` toggle switch (inside of `System UI Tuner`) is for main battery and not for Bluetooth device(

Comment: @alexus: Thanks for updating. Since I don't run marshmallow, wasn't  sure, that's why qualified by saying *am not sure if this setting tweak will help*.  It would be interesting to learn what ear phone OEM has to say. Internet is rich with complaints of similar nature. Thanks for +1

Answer (score 2):

Actually on bare android it's impossible no matter has your device GATT profile with Battery Service or not. This issue has been reported in 2010 and still open. 
So right now you have only two options:

1. Install Cyanogenmod firmware for your phone.
2. Find suitable 3dparty app I'm working on this one [Baton](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.limi.baton)